# How to get 2 values from the same table with a parameter of id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here an sql in which I need to select the id of a user and the status value in the table.

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE user_id='".$id."'
    AND status='add'
    OR status='delete'
```

But then, the outcome is not what I want because it also show the other `id` that has a status value of `delete` which is in my last parameter. Is there any way to filter just the `id` and the `status`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organize your query so that user id condition will not be disturbed by your multiple OR's

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE user_id='".$id."' 
AND (status='add' OR status='delete')
```

Or use in

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE user_id='".$id."' 
AND status IN('add','delete')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take note of that.

Comment: The first solution is not optimal, use the second one instead and forget the solution with the multiple `OR` conditions on [status].

Answer (score 1):

Here the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM user U
WHERE U.user_id = '".$id"'
    AND U.status IN ('add', 'delete')
```

The use of `IN` clause is highly recommended instead of multiple `OR` conditions for the same column.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the status in brackets in order to achieve what you want.

Your sql would look like:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='".$id."' AND (status='add' OR status='delete)'`

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

When combining these conditions, it is important to use brackets so that the database knows what order to evaluate each condition.

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE user_id='".$id."' 
AND (status='add' OR status='delete')
```